# Are AcO- and PhO- better described as soft or hard nucleophiles?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I would presume soft nucleophiles as resonance increases the energy of the HOMO and therefore they favour SN2 over E2?

Comment: Well, many properties like nucleophilicity are expressed while comparing it to another chemical species'. Creating an absolute scale of nucleophilicity only relies on our current knowledge of the "poorest nucleophiles" and the "best nucleophiles"

Comment: Preference of SN2 over E2 is controlled by basicity and solvent. Stronger bases shift preference toward E2. Protic solvents favor E2; polar aprotic solvents favor SN2.